# Why are the database rows are getting deleted automatically sql 2008

Tags: sql-server

Everyday, some of my database rows are getting deleted automatically.

Even the log files are getting deleted, so I am unable to check who deleted those files.

I dont understand what to do.

Comment: Please provide more details. The bit about log files getting deleted sounds like malicious activity (if correct) but without knowing more about the situation difficult to guess if you have been hacked or simply have a badly written delete query or scheduled task.

Comment: Yes, more details are needed. Is this in a production or a test server? Do many people/users/applications have access to it?

Answer (score 2):

If the SQL server is pre-production, you could just yank all delete rights to the target table and wait to see who complains.  If deletes are not allowed on this table anyway, even in production, then it would be a good idea to restrict that functionaity moving forward.

Beyond that, try adding a delete trigger to the table to do auditing.  You can get the source IP address, logged in user info, etc.  You can even rollback the delete if needed.

Here's a good article on using triggers for auditing.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx

Edit:

If you want to stop all deletes on a table, you can use the following trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTable_Delete_Instead_Of_Trigger
ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

     raiserror('Deletes are not allowed.', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: Chris, Thank you for you quick response. Can you please tell me how to delete all rights to target table? and also how to add delete trigger. I am little newbie. Please help me. I have been using recovery software to get back the deleted records, but its become a real mess.

Comment: @georgesmith - Recovery software that reads the transaction log? What logs are being deleted?

Comment: @georgesmith - this company you work for, do they have DBAs or are you the DBA?

Comment: there is no DBA. Actually, I am a freelancer.

Comment: @georgesmith - gotcha. You might want to consult with a DBA and bring them in on this contract.  My email address is listed in my profile - feel free to use it.

Comment: we will do that, but this problem is causing a huge losses for us. Please help us for temporary to avoid the deletion of the rows

Answer (score 1):

Run SQL Profiler against the DB capturing all RPC Completed and SQL BatchCompleted events and review it to find whatever is performing the deletes.